# how return multiple column in join result to view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, join

I want to return multiple column in join result and fill in view model(`VMFoodFoodMeal`).
for example I want to fill `VMFoodFoodMeal` by Join result
Thanks

```
 IEnumerable<VMFoodFoodMeal> _fmt =  (from e in db.FoodProgramMealFood
                        join j in db.Foods on e.FoodId equals j.Id
                 select new
                 {
                     Id = e.Id,
                     Name = j.Name,
                 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to send your join Result to a model without using foreach statement you have to use this code

```
IEnumerable<VMFoodFoodMeal> _fmt = (from e in db.FoodProgramMealFood
                        join j in db.Foods on e.FoodId equals j.Id
                        select new VMFoodFoodMeal()
                         {
                            Id = e.Id,
                            Name = j.Name,
                         });
```

for example in above code I had a view model (`VMFoodFoodMeal`) and want to fill it by join result.
I have to make new instance of my model in `select` and then fill its property.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to understand what you want, but as example you can look [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Join-Operators-dabef4e9) at Group Join section.

Here is an example code from there:

```
public void Linq103() 
{ 
    string[] categories = new string[]{  
        "Beverages",  
        "Condiments",  
        "Vegetables",  
        "Dairy Products",  
        "Seafood" }; 

    List<Product> products = GetProductList(); 

    var q = 
        from c in categories 
        join p in products on c equals p.Category into ps 
        select new { Category = c, Products = ps }; 

    foreach (var v in q) 
    { 
        Console.WriteLine(v.Category + ":"); 
        foreach (var p in v.Products) 
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("   " + p.ProductName); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

result:
 Beverages:
  Chai
  Chang
  GuaranÃ¡ FantÃ¡stica
  Sasquatch Ale
  Steeleye Stout
  CÃ´te de Blaye
  Chartreuse verte
  Ipoh Coffee
  ...